# android 10, Avoid battery optimization on a service

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm trying to start a service that use as much as possibile the network.
I noticed that after a minute and half the bandwidth used is not a lot.
I think that te problem is the battery optimization of android 10.
I put the application in the whitelist of the battery service, but I have the same behavior.

I want to understand if there are other ways to manage this situation.

Comment: Out of curiosity; have you tried the same service with previous Android versions? Did you have different results?

Comment: I don't  have with me smartphones with android 9. so I can't try